# Cannot implement java interface in kotlin due to nullabilty

Tags: java, kotlin

I cannot implement this java interface in kotlin.

```kotlin
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
class FeatureFlagConverter : Converter<String?, FeatureFlags> {
    override fun convert(source: String?): FeatureFlags = FeatureFlags(source ?: "")
}
```

Compiler fails with following:

> Class 'FeatureFlagConverter' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun convert(source: String): FeatureFlags? defined in org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter

**Why?** The interface is pure java interface (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.java) so the `source` parameter in `convert` method might be null, and there is no anotation to hint that it is not null.

*It helps to remove the nullabilty around String. But I do not want to do that since it is Java interface and the `source` parameter in `convert` method might be null. And some java caller might pass null here.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the method you linked says:

> **source** the source object to convert, which must be an instance of `S` (never `null`)

So `S` is required to be non-nullable.

---

The reason Kotlin seems to "know" that the parameter must be non-nullable is likely from nullability annotations. Kotlin supports [several nullability annotations for Java](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations). Spring's nullability annotations are [meta-annotated using JSR-305](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/null-safety.html#jsr-305-meta-annotations), so they are supported.

Although this method doesn't mark `source` as `@NonNull`, I think the whole package is marked with non-nullability as the default [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/package-info.java).

Comment: Thanks for the info about the package level anotation. But still (documentation aside) -  these anotations are not supported by the java compiler. So the java code `converter.convert(null)` will compile but will fail in runtime (because kotlin compiler injects null checks for public signatures).

Comment: In pure Java, there is probably a setting you can turn on to make it an error to pass null to something annotated as non-null.